# Insert wont insert itemID to database table

Tags: php, mysql, database

Ok , so when someone buys item from my site, it is ment to insert that item ID into the database , but it doesnt for some reason.

```
$mysql_host = 'localhost'; //Leave at localhost  
$mysql_user = ''; //DB User  
$mysql_pass = ''; //DB Pass  
$mysql_db = ''; //DB Name  
$file = 'paypal.log'; //Paypal Log Name will be placed in the same location as your ipn.php file
$payer_email = $_REQUEST['payer_email'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$time = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
$paylist = array("5.00" => 15017, "0.01" => 18830, "10.00" => 13840, "10.01" => 13842, "9.99" => 13729, "15.00" => 19111, "60.00" => 1046, "40.00" => 1050, "14.99" => 6199);


// connect db  

$db = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) or die(mysql_error());

$custom = stripslashes(ucwords(strtolower(trim($_REQUEST['custom']))));  
$receiver_email = $_REQUEST['receiver_email'];  
$payment_status = $_REQUEST['payment_status'];  
$mc_gross = $_REQUEST['mc_gross'];
mysql_select_db($mysql_db, $db);  
if ($_REQUEST['debug']){
print $payment_status . '\n';
print (isset($paylist[$mc_gross])) ? 1 : 0 . '\n';
print $receiver_email . '\n';
print $custom . '\n';
}
if ($payment_status == "Completed" && $receiver_email == "justincopp77@yahoo.com" && isset($paylist[$mc_gross])) {  


$query = "INSERT `status` SET `item` = '$itemid' ,`username` = '$custom'";  

$result2 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());  

$prem = mysql_fetch_array($result);  
$somecode = "'$time' '$custom' '$payer_email' '$mc_gross' '$ip'\r\n";

// figure out how much to give
$give = $paylist[$mc_gross];
$itemid = $prem['item'] + $give;  
// $points = mysql_query($prem)  
$qry2 = "SELECT `item` FROM `status` WHERE `username` = '$custom'";
// Log Paypal Transaction
$hak = fopen($file, "a");
fwrite($hak, $somecode);
fclose($hak);

$result2 = mysql_query($qry2) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

[image]

you can see its not putting the item ID in
Does anyone know why it wont inset item id into the database?
What will i need to change to fix it

Thanks in advance

Comment: Now would be a really good time to ditch this deprecated API, and read up on prepared statements

Comment: You're using INSERT to UPDATE a row which is why it does not work as intend.

Comment: I think it needs to say INSERT INTO `status`, not just INSERT 'status'

Comment: You use $itemid (line 34) before you assign a value (line 43).

Answer (score 0):

your sql syntax is wrong

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `status` (item, username) VALUES ('$itemid' ,'$custom')";
```